# Converting a MariaDB-Statement into a Laravel4 Eloquent-Query

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, mariadb

I want to convert a MariaDB-statement into an Eloquent query.
The SQL-Statement is working perfectly, but the Eloquent part unfortunately isn't.

**SQL-Statement (MariaDB)**

> SELECT matchday_id, MAX(ADDDATE(date, INTERVAL 105 MINUTE)) AS matchday_end
>   FROM matches
>   GROUP BY matchday_id
>   HAVING MAX(date) < now();

**Eloquent-Query (Laravel 4)**

> $ended_matchdays = DB::table('matches')
>   ->selectRaw('matchday_id, MAX(ADDDATE(date, INTERVAL 105 MINUTE)) as matchday_end')
>   ->groupBy('matchday_id')
>   ->having('MAX(date)', '<', 'NOW()')
>   ->get();

Error Message (Laravel 4)

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MAX(date)' in 'having clause' (SQL: select matchday_id, MAX(ADDDATE(date, INTERVAL 105 MINUTE)) as end from `matches` group by `matchday_id` having `MAX(date)` < NOW())

I really don't know, why this doesn't work, maybe - like sometimes - a trivial mistake that I don't see..
Hope you guys can help me with that one!

Answer (score 2):

```
->having('MAX(date)', '<', 'NOW()')
```

needs to become:

```
->having(DB::raw('MAX(date)'), '<', 'NOW()')
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap `NOW()` in `DB::raw()` too. Or simply the whole expression `having(DB::raw('MAX(date) < NOW()'))`

Answer (score 0):

**I got it working now.**

Here's the (for me) working code:

> ->having(DB::raw('MAX(date)'), '<', Carbon::now())

I tried to only wrap the MAX(date) part, as well as the whole line in DB::raw(), but both did'nt work.

Now I use the Carbon-Class and it works like a charme =)

Thank you!